# Xamarin Live Player iOS TestFlight

Tags: ios, xamarin, testflight

does anyone has an redeem code for TestFlight, the official registration page shows an application error.

https://fastring.xamarinliveplayer.com/

Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

As of August 10th 2018 Xamarin have stopped TestFlight registration and will no longer be distributing the iOS version of the Xamarin Live Player.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/98529/get-the-latest-previews-for-ios-via-testflight